# Starling keyevents

Tags: flash, actionscript, listener, keyevent, starling-framework

So anyone any idea why it does not working? I want to listen keyevents with my starling class, do I need to focus and if yes how can I do that? Here's a Main class, this is the document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import starling.core.Starling;

public class Main extends Sprite{
    private var starling:Starling

    public function Main(){         
        if (stage)
            init();
        else
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void{
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);                        
        starling = new Starling(ScreenCoorder, stage);
        starling.start();       
    }
}
```

}

And the screencorder class (starts by starling):

```
package  
{

import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class ScreenCoorder extends Sprite{

    public function ScreenCoorder() {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init():void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
    }       

    public function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        trace("so serious");
    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starling Sprite's don't support keypresses, you need to add the listener to the native Stage object like so..

```
this.nativeStage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
```

Comment: thats cool, thanks, anyways why is keyboardevent in starling than?

Comment: It's just the same thing but uses custom methods so you can add the listener to the normal Starling stage. Although the native stage will always be faster so I'd recommend you always use that.

Comment: custom means predefined starling methods?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant Starling uses it's own internal custom methods.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have hooked the keyboard event listener to the ScreenCoorder object, not the starling stage.  Try this:

```
private function init():void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
}
```

Note that is the Starling stage, not the Flash stage.